# How to use node command to run multiple .js files one after the other?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently using the node command to run a few premade scripts. Right now this is what I type into Git:

node file1.js

node file2.js

node file3.js

I have to wait for each one to finish before typing the next "node file.js"

Is there a way to do that for all of the files in the folder as opposed to typing them out one after the other? Thanks!

Comment: Check this npm package. It wil help in your case
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: Thanks, this works great! But is there a way to add a delay of say 5 seconds inbetween each node command? Currently it executes everything at the same time.

Comment: You can create method which executes these node processes after 5 seconds using javscript setTimeout 
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) to first get all files in current dir

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const files = fs.readdirSync('.')
```

Then filter out the `.js` files:

```js
const jsFiles = files.filter(f => f.endsWith('.js'))
```

The execute them one by one using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options):

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process')
for (const file of jsFiles) {
  spawnSync('node', [file], { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' })
}
```

I'm using `spawnSync` so that it'll execute the files synchronously (one-by-one).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `exec()` function to run commands through Javascript. Insert this line of code at the top of `file1.js` and call `exec()` function at the end of the execution and so on.

---

**Example**

index.js

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("dir", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

The output of `node index.js`:

```
stdout:  Volume in drive C is Windows 10
 Volume Serial Number is 3457-05DE

 Directory of C:\dev\node

10.08.2020  20:52    <DIR>          .
10.08.2020  20:52    <DIR>          ..
10.08.2020  20:52    <DIR>          .vscode
10.08.2020  21:39               310 index.js
10.08.2020  21:15               239 package.json
               2 File(s)            549 bytes
```

Comment: You can use `fs.readdir` to get all files in the current dir and execute them all automatically (instead of inserting the next "file1" "file2" manually in each files). You should also probably use `execSync` in that case.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following :( adding that to the start of file1.js only lists the other files in the directory and I still have to manually "node file2" and so on.

Comment: Of course it outputs the list of files in the project directory. To run next js file, you should've substituded the `dir` to `node file2.js`, but as laggingreflex noted, it's not the best approach to resolve your problem.